# Django 1.6 upgrade: "cannot import name BaseHandler"

Tags: django

I am trying to upgrade from Django 1.5.5 to Django 1.6.  Everything tests fine, but when I try to run my django project, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'mail_admins': Cannot resolve 'vbenergyzone.core.utils.log.StaffSuperuserEmailHandler': cannot import name BaseHandler
```

Why?

Here is what I have tried:

- I have removed my custom logging handler code completely.  The project runs fine without any errors.
- I have replaced my custom logging handler code and replaced it with the default handler code.  I get the same error.
- I have tried Django 1.6c1 and get the same error.
- I have created a ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21502.

Here is my stacktrace:

```
20:29:03 web.1    | started with pid 1501
20:29:03 worker.1 | started with pid 1504
20:29:03 web.1    | 2013-11-23 20:29:03 [1503] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
20:29:03 web.1    | 2013-11-23 20:29:03 [1503] [INFO] Listening at: http://192.168.50.4:5000 (1503)
20:29:03 web.1    | 2013-11-23 20:29:03 [1503] [INFO] Using worker: sync
20:29:03 web.1    | 2013-11-23 20:29:03 [1518] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1518
20:29:04 web.1    | 2013-11-23 14:29:04 [1518] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
20:29:04 web.1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/VBEZ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
20:29:04 web.1    |     worker.init_process()
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/VBEZ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
20:29:04 web.1    |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/VBEZ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
20:29:04 web.1    |     self.callable = self.load()
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/VBEZ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
20:29:04 web.1    |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/VBEZ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
20:29:04 web.1    |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/VBEZ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
20:29:04 web.1    |     __import__(module)
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/vagrant/vbenergyzone/wsgi.py", line 23, in <module>
20:29:04 web.1    |     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/VBEZ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
20:29:04 web.1    |     from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/VBEZ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 11, in <module>
20:29:04 web.1    |     from django.core.handlers import base
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/VBEZ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 12, in <module>
20:29:04 web.1    |     from django.db import connections, transaction
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/VBEZ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
20:29:04 web.1    |     signals.request_started.connect(reset_queries)
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/VBEZ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 88, in connect
20:29:04 web.1    |     if settings.DEBUG:
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/VBEZ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
20:29:04 web.1    |     self._setup(name)
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/VBEZ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 50, in _setup
20:29:04 web.1    |     self._configure_logging()
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/VBEZ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 80, in _configure_logging
20:29:04 web.1    |     logging_config_func(self.LOGGING)
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 777, in dictConfig
20:29:04 web.1    |     dictConfigClass(config).configure()
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 575, in configure
20:29:04 web.1    |     '%r: %s' % (name, e))
20:29:04 web.1    | ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'mail_admins': Cannot resolve 'vbenergyzone.core.utils.log.StaffSuperuserEmailHandler': cannot import name BaseHandler
20:29:04 web.1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/VBEZ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
20:29:04 web.1    |     worker.init_process()
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/VBEZ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
20:29:04 web.1    |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/VBEZ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
20:29:04 web.1    |     self.callable = self.load()
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/VBEZ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
20:29:04 web.1    |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/VBEZ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
20:29:04 web.1    |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/VBEZ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
20:29:04 web.1    |     __import__(module)
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/vagrant/vbenergyzone/wsgi.py", line 23, in <module>
20:29:04 web.1    |     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/VBEZ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
20:29:04 web.1    |     from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/VBEZ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 11, in <module>
20:29:04 web.1    |     from django.core.handlers import base
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/VBEZ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 12, in <module>
20:29:04 web.1    |     from django.db import connections, transaction
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/VBEZ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
20:29:04 web.1    |     signals.request_started.connect(reset_queries)
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/VBEZ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 88, in connect
20:29:04 web.1    |     if settings.DEBUG:
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/VBEZ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
20:29:04 web.1    |     self._setup(name)
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/VBEZ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 50, in _setup
20:29:04 web.1    |     self._configure_logging()
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/VBEZ/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 80, in _configure_logging
20:29:04 web.1    |     logging_config_func(self.LOGGING)
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 777, in dictConfig
20:29:04 web.1    |     dictConfigClass(config).configure()
20:29:04 web.1    |   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 575, in configure
20:29:04 web.1    |     '%r: %s' % (name, e))
20:29:04 web.1    | ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'mail_admins': Cannot resolve 'vbenergyzone.core.utils.log.StaffSuperuserEmailHandler': cannot import name BaseHandler
```

Here is my logging configuration:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'filters': {
         'require_debug_false': {
             '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
         }
     },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
        },
        'console':{
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            # 'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'class': 'vbenergyzone.core.utils.log.StaffSuperuserEmailHandler',
            'filters': [],
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'vbenergyzone': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'mail_admins'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my custom logger:

```
"""
Logging utilities
"""
import logging
import traceback

from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

from django.views.debug import get_exception_reporter_filter

from vbenergyzone.core import send_message

# ==============================================================================

class StaffSuperuserEmailHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        try:
            request = record.request
            domain = Site.objects.get_current().domain

            subject = 'User %s experienced an error on %s: %s' % \
                (request.user, domain, record.getMessage())

            filter = get_exception_reporter_filter(request)
            request_repr = filter.get_request_repr(request)
        except Exception:
            subject = '%s: %s' % (
                record.levelname,
                record.getMessage(),
            )

            request = None
            request_repr = "Request repr() unavailable."

        if record.exc_info:
            exc_info = record.exc_info
            stack_trace = \
                '\n'.join(traceback.format_exception(*record.exc_info))
        else:
            exc_info = (None, record.getMessage(), None)
            stack_trace = 'No stack trace available'

        context_object = {
            'message':      record.getMessage(),
            'request':      request,
            'request_repr': request_repr,
            'stack_trace':  stack_trace,
        }

        send_message(
            context_object=context_object,
            html_template='core/email/staff_super_email_handler.html',
            send_to_staff_and_superusers=True,
            subject=self.format_subject(subject),
            text_template='core/email/staff_super_email_handler.txt',
        )

    def format_subject(self, subject):
        """
        Escape CR and LF characters, and limit length.
        RFC 2822's hard limit is 998 characters per line. So, minus "Subject: "
        the actual subject must be no longer than 989 characters.
        """
        formatted_subject = subject.replace('\n', '\\n').replace('\r', '\\r')
        return formatted_subject[:989]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug with a patch that will be coming out with Django 1.6.1.  In the meantime, this commit includes the patch: https://github.com/django/django/commit/432de546113942be60089a879371073ad09fb4fe.

Thanks to claudep and bmispelon at the Django project for helping me with this!